# Graph data structure in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures, rubygems, graph-algorithm

**EDIT:**

How would you represent a graph (undirected) in ruby. Some example might help. Or is There any class or something to make it easier?

**Original Question:**

Similar: [Tree and graph data structures in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194812/tree-and-graph-data-structures-in-ruby)
But its years old.
So my question is

Is there any gem or library for representing graphs. I need to implement a undirected graph for busstops to find a shortest distance.

I have looked at GRATR and Graphy. But they are no longer maintained and possibly outdated. (I'm not sure).
If possible something which will support on ruby 2.0.0

Or should i write my own classes for the graph repsentation and if so i think i would need an adjanceny list. How to implement that aswell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated the question to stackoverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

[RubyTree](http://rubytree.rubyforge.org/) is a general purpose tree data structure for Ruby. We've found it to be quite useful across many contexts.

Comment: is it any good at graph structures too?